# Pasar una instancia de una clase desde otra clase por el constructor a un formulario padre. C# winform

Tags: herencia, inyeccion-de-dependencias, parametros

Tengo la case genérica "Negocio" que implementa una interfaces genérica "INegocio".

Las clases genéricas  "sectorN", "zonaN" y "tiposN" heredan de la clase genérica "Negocio".

Tengo el formulario  mantenimiento-padre.

Los formularios "Sector", "Zona" y "Tipos" que heredan de mantenimiento-padre.

En el Formulario "Sector" hago uso de la clase "sectorN", y quiero pasársela por el constructor a mantenimiento-padre.

En el Formulario "Zona" hago uso de la clase "zonaN", y quiero pasársela por el constructor a mantenimiento-padre.

En el Formulario "Tipos" hago uso de la clase "tiposN", y quiero pasársela por el constructor a mantenimiento-padre.

Pero con un solo parámetro.

Pensé que podía hacer lo siguiente:

public MantenimientoPadre(Negocio Modelo)    ---pero Negocio es generico asi que:

public MantenimientoPadre(Negocios<> Modelo) ----pero noce que poner entre <>.

intente:

public MantenimientoPadre( Negocios< null > Modelo ) --- pero me dice que : "se espera un tipo".

[image: Imagen descriptiva]

Comment: puedes actualizar la pregunta ''Pasar parámetro genérico al constructor de una clase base''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes crear un **Factory** EJ: `INegociosFactory` y ponerla en los constructores de los formularios **"SectorN"**, **"ZonaN"** y **"TiposN"**.

```
public SectorN(INegociosFactory negociosFactory) : base(negociosFactory) { }
```

#### Utilizando **Ninject**

```
public class NegociosFactory : INegociosFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _Kernel;

    public NegociosFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _Kernel = kernel;
    }

    public T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _Kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

> Actualización

Puedes crear una clase base genérica **MantenimientoPadre**.

```
public class MantenimientoPadre<T> : Form
{
    private readonly Negocio<T> _negocio;

    // constructor vacío para el diseñador.
    public MantenimientoPadre() {}

    public MantenimientoPadre(Negocio<T> negocio)
    {
        Load += FormBase_Load;
        _command = command;
    }

    private void MantenimientoPadre_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

En las subclases debes hacer lo siguiente.

```
public partial SectorN : MantenimientoPadre<SectorDB>
{
    public SectorN(SectorN<SectorDB> negocios) : base(negocios)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial ZonaN : MantenimientoPadre<SectorDB>
{
    public ZonaN(ZonaN<SectorDB> negocios) : base(negocios)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial TiposN : MantenimientoPadre<SectorDB>
{
    public TiposN(TiposN<SectorDB> negocios) : base(negocios)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: si hago el  mantenimientoPadre genérico, pues me causa errores masivos pues ya mantenimientoPadre no heredaría de Form

Comment: @LuisEduardoFrias si te fue de utilidad, puedes marcar como mejor respuesta.